# Prevent repeated sequence in domain url

Tags: regex

I have this regex: https://regex101.com/r/UjUujN/1

```
^((https?):\/\/)?(www.)?(?!.*(https?|www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$
```

While it works mostly okay, problem is that it also matches domains with repeated words. For example, it would match

```
com.com.com.com
h.test.com.test.com.com.com.com.test
```

Anyone have a suggestion how to modify regex pattern in order to prevent repeating of sequences?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, always simplify your sample at minimum like I does to isolate the issue:

```
^([a-z]+).*?(?!\.\1)(?:\.[a-z]+)+$
 ^------^        ^^
capture group  captured group
```

##### [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t2zoDi/1)